# Unable to use "test" as value in javascript but can use a number like 1

Tags: javascript

I am running into an issue where I cannot use a value based on words to trigger a form change with the onchange option. I run into an issue were the browser returns that it cannot find the variable  If I assign values that are numeric for the options everything works. The issue being here that I need a value word to be entered into the database and not a value number. I know this is not the clearest description but any help would be great.

```
function test(){
    var selopt = document.getElementById("topic").value;
    if (selopt == test) {
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";
    }
    if (selopt == 2) {
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: If your issue is related only to javascript, post the javascript code resulting from evaluating the php code, instead of the php code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean

```
if (selopt == test)
```

What is `test`? It is a variable, not a string. You are checking to see if `selopt` is equal to a function.

```
if (selopt == "test")
```